# Error when running tutorial01_sumo.ipynb in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, flow-project

I'm following the `flow/tutorials/README.md` to set up the tutorial environment, but I still have some errors.

When I open the jupyter notebook interface, there are five environments in the 'kernel': `python2`, `python[conda env:enter]`, `python[conda env:flow]`, `python[conda root]`, `python[default]`. These kernels I have tried, but I still get an error.

(The `"enter"` in python env `[conda env:enter]` is my own downloaded anaconda.)

```
from flow.scenarios.loop import LoopScenario
```

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 from flow.scenarios.loop import LoopScenario
>
> ImportError: No module named 'flow'```

Comment: I can successfully import tensorflow in jupyter notebook，but i don't know why "Flow" can't.

Comment: BTW:I am running in the case of the "Python[conda env:flow]", show "ImportError: No module named flow"

Answer (score 1):

Open a new terminal and run the following:

```
cd /
source activate flow
python
```

(`cd /` is to make sure `flow` is not in the folder you run `python` from)

Then in the Python interface that opens, run `import flow`.

Do you get an error when trying to import?

Comment: Yes! i have an ImportError: No module named flow. when I input "python", the terminal show  "python 3.5.2", But I remember that the python version of the anaconda I installed is 3.6.5. Is this the reason?

Comment: This means that you don't have flow installed within the current anaconda environment. You can try to run the same commands but replace `python` by `python3.6` and see if you get the import error. Otherwise, redo the part of the installation instructions where you have to `pip install -e flow` (something like that) to add flow to the environment (after having done source activate flow!).

Comment: `pip install -e .` actually, in the folder that contains the `setup.py` file.

Comment: Okay, according to what you said, I have reconfigured the environment. Now I can run it in the jupyter notebook.Thank you for your answer.